# Python Selenium - No Such Element Found... I'm Lost

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, classname

I am trying to click on an element that should send me to the next page, however, I can't seem to properly locate it or even locate any item on the page.

HTML Code for Element

```
<a data-qa="menu-button" 
class="HeaderMenu__HeaderItemButton-kr6p0e-0 hbeYmr MenuButton__MenuButtonWrapper-dq0g44-0 imLDTG" 
data-cv-test="headerSearchLink" 
href="/cars" 
target="_self">Search Cars
</a>
```

[Visual of what I'm trying to click on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QK1UK.jpg)

My code that does not work (I have the proper import statements)

```
PATH = "my_path_to_chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://www.carvana.com")
link = driver.find_element_by_class_name('HeaderMenu__HeaderItemButton-kr6p0e-0 hbeYmr MenuButton__MenuButtonWrapper-dq0g44-0 imLDTG')
link.click()
```

I have tried searching by class name using this approach and just get this error message

```
link = driver.find_element_by_class_name('HeaderMenu__HeaderItemButton-kr6p0e-0 hbeYmr MenuButton__MenuButtonWrapper-dq0g44-0 imLDTG')
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 564, in find_element_by_class_name
return self.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=name)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".HeaderMenu__HeaderItemButton-kr6p0e-0 hbeYmr MenuButton__MenuButtonWrapper-dq0g44-0 imLDTG"}
(Session info: chrome=xx.x.xxxx.xxx)
```

I have also tried searching by CSS selector. I even did a little sanity check and searched for the very first line of html code on the website and for some reason it gave me the same error. Anything helps... thank you!

Comment: when there's a space in the class attribute it means there are more than one.  Use . operator like so: link = driver.find_element_by_class_name('.HeaderMenu__HeaderItemButton-kr6p0e-0.hbeYmr MenuButton__MenuButtonWrapper-dq0g44-0.imLDTG') (replace space with ".") Could also target "data-qa" attribute with xpath of //a[@data-qa="menu-button"] https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_class.asp

Comment: Did you check if the element you are trying to access is inside a frame?

Comment: @pcalkins the xpath targeting data-cv-test worked. Thank you for the suggestion. However, the class name search still gave me the same error. I am just going to use xpath from here on out.

Comment: Just letting you know, class name you used to identify the element returns 3 elements. So always make sure to write a unique locator

Comment: Thank you, what line of code did you use to access the elements. For some reason none of mine are working with that class name. @itronic1990

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you have spaces in   the class name. The class name function doesn't work for that, I would suggest trying

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.HeaderMenu__HeaderItemButton-kr6p0e-0.hbeYmr.MenuButton__MenuButtonWrapper-dq0g44-0.imLDTG')
```

Comment: Perfect, that worked... is there a reason why you are searching by css selector vs. class name?

Comment: All the function `driver.find_element_by_class_name(name)` even does, I think, is stick a dot in front of `name` and run `driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.' + name)`. Which doesn't work in your case because with the spaces in the class name it is not interpreted correctly in a css selector, you have to use one like above.

Answer (score 0):

> driver.find_element_by_class_name('HeaderMenu__HeaderItemButton-kr6p0e-0
> hbeYmr MenuButton__MenuButtonWrapper-dq0g44-0 imLDTG')

This code give return a node list and u can't click it  , you may try get the first element , so  here is the code :

> driver.find_element_by_class_name('HeaderMenu__HeaderItemButton-kr6p0e-0
> hbeYmr MenuButton__MenuButtonWrapper-dq0g44-0 imLDTG')[0]

Or   bye doing this in the console of the navigator with js like this :

> document.getElementByNames('HeaderMenu__HeaderItemButton-kr6p0e-0
> hbeYmr MenuButton__MenuButtonWrapper-dq0g44-0 imLDTG')[0]

Comment: Thank you. For some reason when I run that same line of code and try to print it I get an error when it tries to access the element. Am I using an older version of selenium?

Comment: i don't think so , u can do this , wd.execute_script('return document.getElementByNames("HeaderMenu__HeaderItemButton-kr6p0e-0 hbeYmr MenuButton__MenuButtonWrapper-dq0g44-0 imLDTG")[0])')